# Is there distinction between $(C/poly)\cap(coC/poly)$ and $(C\cap coC)/poly$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, closure-properties, nondeterminism, circuits

Let $C$ be an uniform complexity class for example $NL$ or $NP$. Is there distinction between $(C/poly)\cap(coC/poly)$ and $(C\cap coC)/poly$?

Comment: What is $A/poly$ for an arbitrary complexity class? We usually define non uniform classes with respect to some underlying model, e.g. time/space bounded machines with advice.

Comment: @Ariel If $C$ is any class of languages, and $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, then $L\in C/f(n)$ iff there exists a language $L'\in C$ and a sequence of advice strings $\{a_n:n\in\mathbb N\}$ such that $|a_n|\le f(n)$ and $w\in L\iff(w,a_{|w|})\in L'$. Then $C/\mathrm{poly}=\bigcup_{c\in\mathbb N}C/n^c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\co{\mathrm{co}}\def\poly{\mathrm{poly}}\def\N{\mathbb N}$A language $L$ is in $(C/\poly)\cap(\co C/\poly)$ iff there are languages
$$L_0\in C,\qquad L_1\in\co C,$$
and sequences of advice strings $\{a_{0,n}:n\in\N\}$, $\{a_{1,n}:n\in\N\}$ such that
$$|a_{0,n}|,|a_{1,n}|=n^{O(1)},$$
and for any $n\in\N$ and $w\in\{0,1\}^n$,
$$w\in L\iff(w,a_{0,n})\in L_0\iff(w,a_{1,n})\in L_1.$$
(I’m assuming the class $C$ is robust enough so that the exact representation of $(w,a)$ does not matter.)

In contrast, $L$ is in $(C\cap\co C)/\poly$ iff there exists a *single* language
$$L'\in C\cap\co C$$
and a sequence of strings $\{a'_n:n\in\N\}$ such that
$$|a'_n|=n^{O(1)},$$
and for any $w\in\{0,1\}^n$,
$$w\in L\iff(w,a_n)\in L'.$$

Thus, we trivially have the inclusion
$$(C\cap\co C)/\poly\subseteq(C/\poly)\cap(\co C/\poly)$$
as we can just put $L_0=L_1:=L'$, $a_{0,n}=a_{1,n}:=a'_n$. However, there is no a priori reason for the reverse inclusion to hold: while we can easily combine $a_{0,n}$ and $a_{1,n}$ to a single advice $a'_n=(a_{0,n},a_{1,n})$, there is in general no way how to unify $L_0\in C$ and $L_1\in\co C$ to a single language $L'\in C\cap\co C$.

For the specific examples, it seems reasonable to conjecture that
$$\def\np{\mathrm{NP}}(\np\cap\co\np)/\poly\subsetneq(\np/\poly)\cap(\co\np/\poly),$$
but since this implies various hard separations (in particular, $\np\ne\co\np$ and $\np\nsubseteq\mathrm P/\poly$), we don’t know how to prove that.

On the other hand, the Immerman–Szelepcsényi theorem ensures that $\def\nl{\mathrm{NL}}\nl=\co\nl$, hence
$$\nl/\poly=\co\nl/\poly=(\nl/\poly)\cap(\co\nl/\poly)=(\nl\cap\co\nl)/\poly.$$

For an example (even if a bit contrived) with an unconditional separation, let $\def\nul{\mathrm{NULL}}\nul$ denote the class of languages of asymptotic density $0$: i.e., if $L\subseteq\{0,1\}^*$, then
$$L\in\nul\iff\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|L\cap\{0,1\}^n|}{2^n}=0.$$
Then $\nul\cap\co\nul=\varnothing$, hence also
$$(\nul\cap\co\nul)/\poly=\varnothing.$$
On the other hand,
$$(\nul/\poly)\cap(\co\nul/\poly)$$
is the class of *all* languages: for any language $L$, define
$$L_0=\{(w,0^n):w\in L,n=|w|\}\in\nul$$
and
$$L_1=\overline{\{(w,0^n):w\in\overline L,n=|w|\}}\in\co\nul.$$
Then we have
$$w\in L\iff(w,0^n)\in L_0\iff(w,0^n)\in L_1$$
for any $w\in\{0,1\}^n$.